# No rep for edits once user has edit privileges, even below 1000?

Tags: bug, reputation, edits, privileges

On the [Law.SE Beta](http://law.stackexchange.com) I earned edit privileges at 500 total rep, and ever since then my edits have earned no rep.  I have earned nowhere near the 1000 rep limit from edits suggested in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation).

Is this intentional or is it a bug?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is intentional. You only earn reputation from approved suggested edits. If you're not actually *suggesting* edits anymore, then you can't earn reputation from them.

The idea of giving reputation for approved edits is to give users a little extra boost in order to obtain those privileges, as well as let them reach some of the other lower-level privileges, without having to know a *whole lot* about the site's topic in order to gain all that reputation through questions and answers. By utilizing them, you can effectively lower the barrier of reaching full editing privileges by half on a fully graduated site. That's half as many questions and answers you have to post before you're able to start editing on your own without other's approval.

You *can* still earn reputation from suggested edits on tag wikis, because you don't earn full editing privileges on those until you reach the trusted user privilege at 2,000 reputation (on beta sites).

Comment: If that's the intention it seems incredibly disproportionate and in need of calibration. I've edited almost 50 questions on DIY.SE, vs. < 10 on Law.SE. But I'm little more than a quarter of the way to "trusted user" on the former. If a private beta user can be trusted to edit after a handful of questions and answers, why queue edits for review after months of positive activity on a regular site? (And, though perhaps this merits a separate question: why on betas put the tag edit privilege so far out of reach? I hardly even bother to suggest tag edits because they are approved so infrequently.)

Comment: @feetwet The rep differences are in part a practicality thing; users generally have lower rep on private beta than on public beta than on graduated sites, so rep thresholds are lower to enable community moderation.